# Is there a way to mathematically model the stress/strain graph of a material after the limit of proportionality?

Tags: material-science, stress-strain, models

I am currently working on an application that simulates physics experiements, and am struggling to find a way to model the graph after the limit of proportionality. I have constrained the simulation to using steel as the material being stretched, and thus can use its Young's Modulus to find the stress/strain up to the limit of proportionality. Keeping the material constant and the wire of a variable diameter, is there a way to model the rest of the graph, up to the materials fracture point? The only way I have found is to actually do the experiment and work out the stress/strain values manually, but this becomes a problem since the diameter of my wire isn't constant.

[image: Stress/Strain graph]

Comment: An online search for `modeling plasticity "stress-strain diagram"` gives a very large number of possible models one could use. [Example.](http://metalurji.mu.edu.tr/Icerik/metalurji.mu.edu.tr/Sayfa/Plasticity%20W8(1).pdf).

Answer (score 1):

to accurately represent the curve past the yield strength point, you must include a whole list of new physics in your model which are very complicated, nonlinear, and highly dependent on the strain rate of the test, the phase composition of the alloy under test, its grain size, and its processing history. These things are so subtle and complex that the theoretical models are not of much use- especially since the actual stress-strain test is so easily performed on a test sample.